# Redisearch not work in a cluster?

Tags: python, redis, redisearch

Our team are thinking of using redisearch on top Elasticsearch as a store unit for real time data. 
When looking at the document:
https://oss.redislabs.com/redisearch/Administration/
I see: *RediSearch will not work correctly on a cluster*. Does it mean in order to use redisearch, we have to use the commercial version and cant build redisearch cluster by ourself?
Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

RediSearch will "agree" to work on a cluster setup, but that will not help you much. Creating a clustered search engine requires an additional coordination layer. Right now that's available only for the commercial version - or you can opt to write one on your own! :)

(Disclosure: I'm the original author of RediSearch, although I do not work for Redis Labs nor contribute to the project anymore).

Answer (score 5):

RediSearch 2.0 can now support running in a cluster through the use of the new RSCoordinator module.

Checkout the [introduction](https://redislabs.com/blog/introducing-redisearch-2-0/) to RediSearch 2.0 as well as the [RSCoordinator](https://github.com/RediSearch/RSCoordinator) project on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone was wondering the `RSCoordinator` is integrated into Redis Search =>2.2